# Getting FloatingPointError instead of ZeroDivisionError when dividing by zero

Tags: python, floating-point, division

I'm running a very time-consuming post-processor in Python and have encountered a `FloatingPointError` where I was expecting a `ZeroDivisionError`.

My code captured the possibility of a `ZeroDivisionError` in a `try` `except` statement:

```
try: a = b / abs(c) 
except ZeroDivisionError: a = 'divZero'
```

However, I get the following error:

```
FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in divide
```

Why might I get this error?

Comment: what are the values of `b` and `c`?

Comment: yeah, try printing `c`. It might not be `0`, but some really small number due to numerical error.

Comment: `c` is `0.0`.  I wouldn't know exactly what `b` is without running the code again and that would take a little while, but it is a floating point number taken from an array (e.g. `43.3E3/2` )

Comment: We can't reproduce this without the values of `b` and `c`

Comment: More importantly than the values, please show the _types_ of `b` and `c` (e.g., what does `print(type(b))` show?). I strongly suspect that at least one of `b` and `c` is a NumPy scalar rather than a regular Python `float`.

Comment: The example is incomplete and not verifiable. Please provide the missing information (the definition of the variables). https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if:

- You are using numpy, and
- You have an [error state](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html#numpy.errstate) for `division` set to `error`.

Since you have stated you have taken the number from an array, it appears likely those are numpy versions.  You can check the error state with [`numpy.geterr()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.geterr.html).  You have probably called either `numpy.seterr()` or `numpy.errstate()` somewhere in your code, or a library you are using has.

For example, you can get the `FloatingPointError` as follows:

```
In [22]: np.seterr(divide="raise")
Out[22]: {'divide': 'raise', 'over': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore', 'invalid': 'warn'}

In [24]: b = np.float32(1)

In [25]: c = np.float32(0)

In [26]: a = b / c
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FloatingPointError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-809085b5049b> in <module>()
----> 1 a = b / c

FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in float_scalars
```

If `b` and `c` are numpy integers rather than floats, `float_scalars` will be `short_scalars` instead.  Note that numpy objects *never* result in a `ZeroDivisionError`.  If you have the error state `divide='ignore'` or `divide='warn'`, the result of `a / 0` will be `inf`, and the result of `a // 0` will be `0`.

Although I cannot reproduce your *exact* error message, it may be that this is due to different versions of `numpy` (I`m on 1.14.5).